# Calling a function to the alter constraints using UITapGestureRecognizer in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, button, constraints

This code has a button when pressed a large blue box becomes a small blue box. How can the code be written so that when the blue box is touched it will transform into the small box without the need for a button. 
    import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let colorview = UIView()
    var initialc = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        colorview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        colorview.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        self.view.addSubview((colorview))

        let leadingc = colorview.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.leadingAnchor)
        let trailingC = colorview.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.trailingAnchor)
        let topc = colorview.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.topAnchor)
        let bottomc = colorview.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -50)

        initialc.appendContentsOf([leadingc,trailingC,topc,bottomc])
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(initialc)


    }
    @IBAction func changethebleep(sender: AnyObject) {

        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(initialc)

        let widthc = colorview.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(100)
        let heightc = colorview.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(100)
        let centerxc = colorview.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerXAnchor)
        let centeryc = colorview.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerYAnchor)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([widthc,heightc,centerxc,centeryc])

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: You could use a tap gesture recognizer

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad()

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(ViewController.myFunction(_:)))
    colorview.userInteractionEnabled = true
    colorview.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

In myFunction()

```
func myFunction(sender: AnyObject) {

    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(initialc)

    let widthc = colorview.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(100)
    let heightc = colorview.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(100)
    let centerxc = colorview.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerXAnchor)
    let centeryc = colorview.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerYAnchor)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([widthc,heightc,centerxc,centeryc])

}
```

By adding a tap gesture recognizer, you do not need a button. The tap gesture calls the function that handles the constraints. I've tested the code in my own project and it all works as it should.

Good Luck!